# AWS Lambda cannot read a database on AWS Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, boto3

Hi I have a database structure that is like this on redshift:

[image]

When I query the vault_control database using the following query, it works on DBeaver:

```
select distinct(solution_name) from vault_control;
```

I get the following results, which is what I want:

[image]

However, I have code that is connecting to reshift from lambda via boto3 like this:

```
import json
import boto3
import time


query_string = "select distinct(solution_name) from vault_control;"

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
    execution_id = client.execute_statement(
    ClusterIdentifier='id',
    Database='cloudbi',
    DbUser='user',
    Sql=query_string,
     )['Id']
    print(f'Execution started with ID {execution_id}')




    status = client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)['Status']
    while status not in ['FINISHED','ABORTED','FAILED']:
        time.sleep(10)
        status = client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)['Status']
    print(f'Execution {execution_id} finished with status {status}')


    if status == 'FINISHED':
        columns = [c['label'] for c in client.get_statement_result(Id=execution_id)['ColumnMetadata']]
        records = client.get_statement_result(Id=execution_id)['Records']
    print(f'SUCCESS. Found {len(records)} records')

else:
    print(f'Failed with Error: {client.describe_statement(Id=execution_id)["Error"]}')
```

I am getting an error with :

```
Execution f11d86c5-28fd-45d3-a1bf-7b17 finished with status FAILED
Failed with Error: ERROR: relation "vault_control" does not exist
```

Can someone please assist?

Comment: Your screenshot is showing `vault_control` as a **schema**. Is there also a **table** with the same name? If so, try: `SELECT ... FROM vault_control.vault_control`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot Run a query on AWS Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567096/cannot-run-a-query-on-aws-redshift)