# Cannot Run a query on AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Hi I am experiencing a weird scenario, I have a query that I running on Dbeaver and it works:

[image]

But when I run the same query on aws redshift it's not working, I get relation doesn't exist:

[image]

Please help if you can. Dbeaver connects to redshift.

Comment: Note that `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_. When used as `select distinct`, unique _rows_ are returned. Remove those extra pair of parentheses and simply write `select distinct solution_name from ...`, to make code clearer - for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like vault_control is a schema so your SQL would not normally work - as it would expect a table/view here. It may be that Dbeaver is doing something in the background, such as querying the information schema, that allows you to query for the tables in a schema like that - but it's not standard SQL

Comment: I see, is there a way to express in sql in such a way that is works?

Comment: You would need to write a SQL query against the appropriate system catalog table, probably this one: PG_TABLE_DEF